# handling users incorrect input type via $_POST or $_GET supergobal

Tags: php, html, validation

I understand the basic handling of validation, but if users alter the form from

```
<input name="yourname">
```

to

```
<input name="yourname[array][haha][I][will][try][to][crack][your][system]">
```

How should I deal with this when I am expecting a string but I am provided an array of unknown depth? Currently, I only let my back-end to accept 1 depth of multi dimensional array, but I think that's strict and not flexible for further reuse.

I guess my server-side code is too unclear, so I will remove it and ask for general guidelines of how to deal with an unexpected value type.

Comment: Why do you have the user's name as a multi-dimensional array? Regardless, we'd need to see more of the code to give you a better response.

Comment: No, we need the serverside code. You can always use typehinting and convert data types to strings.

Comment: @DanielRuf consider the original code using function like using `isset($postvalue)` and `!is_array($postvalue)`...

Comment: @Andrew and where should there be a security hole? If you check and typehint the values it should be ok. You can also check if the type is an array and its length and depth.

Comment: @DanielRuf I feel like thats too strict and want to be more flexible. like allowing a dynamic depth of array. what would be a good alternative ??

Comment: Then you have to check on the server side the form and its fields. Make some schema for form_name + field_name => field_type..

Comment: @Andrew, you can use encryption, instead of using such gibberish. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I just got notice that my post is moved to here from security forum....without any previous inform...anyways....can you elaborate a bit more on encrypting input field??

Comment: @Andrew I am writing an answer for you.

Comment: I don’t really get what you are asking here. If your script expects a certain parameter name/data in a certain structure – then _validate_ that the data you got is in that form, and if not reject it.

Comment: @CBroe yes, but if one day I wanted to have a input with 2 depth array then I will need to rewrite the validation system to accept it (previous only detect 1 depth), `name="yourname[surname]"` to `name=yourname["surname"]["changed_surname"]`

Comment: Of course your validation needs to be adapted, because these are two totally different validation requirements … If in one place you want your script to accept a string value only for the parameter named `yourname`, but in another place you want it to be an array – then you have to write two different pieces of validation logic to cover each case.

Comment: @CBroe I understand what you mean, if I have a case for each input types that will be fine. but the system will not be as much as flexible, so I concluded maybe there's a general guidelines for incorrect users input type?? I dont know why I came up with this question, just think its funny if possible to break it in the first place. I actually tried in one place, and it return `array`, guess thats the `strlen` kicking for version before 5.3.0

Comment: I had thought of using `error_reporting(0);` to suppress the warning for invalid type, but I guess its not a good idea of this since im already validating and it should also covered in each test case...lol

Comment: _“maybe there's a general guidelines for incorrect users input type”_ – to recognize something as “incorrect”, you must first of all define what _correct_ would be. And if you have two different definitions of “correct” in tow different places, then you need to have two different validation logics as well. You can of course set up a more general validation scheme, that allows you to specify what parameter names and with which values/data structure you expect resp. want to consider valid/correct – so less hard-coded validation logic, more towards a configurable system.

Comment: @CBroe in your respective, should I close this topic as it is too board to be answered ?? since it might be, like you said, more towards on configurable system than validation logic